# ColdFusion 2016 Installation

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I can't run ColdFusion 2016 after installed. I open terminal window and type in this command:

```
/Applications/Coldfusion2016/cfusion/bin/coldfusion start
```

After that, it prompted me to type the command: sudo ./coldfusion start

> You must be the root user to configure the ColdFusion connector.
>   Start ColdFusion as "sudo ./coldfusion start" to configure the
>   connector. Once connector has been configured, start ColdFusion as
>   "./coldfusion start" to run ColdFusion as non-root user".

I did all the steps however it failed to run. Can anyone help me with this problem? I greatly appreciate your answer.

[image: Screen shot of commands]

Comment: According to your screenshot, you didn't type the sudo command correctly.  "command not found".  Why didn't you just add "sudo" to the command you typed the first time?

Comment: (Edit) *You must be the root user to configure the ColdFusion connector.* I do not mean this sarcastically, but did you read the error message? Not a Mac user, but going strictly off what it says, it sounds like you must use `sudo` for the first command. That said, this is better suited for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 6):

You literally need to add the [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) command to the beginning of your start command. MacOS is requiring admin access to start the server.

`sudo /Applications/Coldfusion2016/cfusion/bin/coldfusion start`

When this runs, you'll be prompted for your admin password before it starts.